# ArcGIS Pro - How do I add multiple points and polygons in one drop down menu with different symbology for each

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am a SUPER beginner to ArcGIS Pro and couldn't figure it out. How do I add multiple points and polygons in one drop down menu in contents with different symbology for each? I've tried making a feature class and then going into 'edit' and 'create' but it just makes every point the same point with the same symbology, if that makes sense??

I'm trying to make a map of my neighbourhood to categorize different tree species and wanted to add points of different trees myself inside ArcGIS without having to use Avenza or something like that - and also wanted it under one drop down menu in contents so it isn't confusing.

Comment: If you are trying to symbolize trees based on species, you would need to have that data stored as an attribute. Then you can symbolize based on "Unique Values" and create a different symbol for each type. As for a drop down menu, I am not sure how that relates to ArcGIS Pro.